# Let the user choose to turn off oneboxing

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

Recently I've moved from a large 1080p screen to a smaller one, and I never noticed this before, but holy crap, oneboxing is incredibly annoying if you don't have a large quantity of screen space.

Please implement a feature where the user can choose to turn off oneboxing.

Comment: Related: [Ability to minimize oneboxes in chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203302/) and [Make chat oneboxing smaller and less obnoxious - click to enlarge instead](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158524/make-chat-oneboxing-smaller-and-less-obnoxious-click-to-enlarge-instead)

Comment: Also related: [Overrides/preferences for chat oneboxing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138314/overrides-preferences-for-chat-oneboxing)