# Why is the maximum image size one can upload in the chat twice larger than the maximum image size one can upload in a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, chat, images, uploader, imgur

The upload limit for images and GIF files in questions and answers is [2 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261925/178179), while the chat uploader has a size limit of [4 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395765/178179) for JPG and PNG (I haven't looked at GIF). In both cases, large images are [lossily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333607/178179) compressed, but I wonder: Why is the maximum image size that one can upload in the chat two times larger than the maximum image size that one can upload in a question or answer?

Comment: Probably because the configuration says so. At work, I keep getting into upload constraints (not often, thankfully) because I never comprehend all the places they need to be set; in IIS, in the .NET code, and/or in some obscure configuration file ...

Comment: @Glorfindel thanks yes the question implies why this configuration, and why a human chose this config, etc. :)

Comment: Most likely because different people worked on chat and Q&A and they made different choices because they didn't realise it was important to consult with each other, and maybe it actually wasn't.