# Mention the maximum image size for images uploaded in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, images, uploader

The maximum image size one can upload in the chat is [4 MiB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/395765/178179) (at least for JPG and PNG files, one day someone should look at GIF files). The limit is not mentioned in the chat.

Feature request: Mention the maximum image size for images uploaded in chat. (uploaded, and not just linked to).

One motivation: it'll help explain why some images fail to upload:

[image]

Comment: This is probably a question to ask after the Imgur migration is finished. We don't know exactly what that will entail.

Comment: @Laurel Can also be addressed while they migrate, as the migration will require some UI changes such as removing mentions of imgur.com