I am unable to upload images with size around 1MB or larger in chat rooms
I guess the official limit is 3MB. But I can't upload them unless they are less than around 1MB. I tested multiple images in different browsers. Same result.
There is no error message in the UI (it just keeps saying "Uploading" forever), but in console I see this:

I have a 40 Mbps Internet connection and I doubt this is the culprit.

There is error behind the scenes: 413 Payload Too Large.

The tested limit was 4MiB: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274156/limit-the-size-of-images-uploaded-into-chat/395765#395765 but they migrated to Google Cloud Platform recently so that might have changed some limits.

@rene and the limit in the Q&A sites uploader was totally removed, letting even 10MB images, and scaling them down.

@ShadowWizard that sounds ... weird.

@rene see this. (turns out 10MB is the hard limit)

@ShadowWizard but that is the pubplat image uploader. Bonfire is separate from that, right? Only backend storage is the same but from there everything up the layers is different.

@rene if you mean the Stacks Editor uploader, it's considered a bug that it's not supporting same size as the "ordinary" editor, and reported already.

Fixed now, the limit is now back to the 4 MB it was before. As rene guessed, this was caused by the cloud migration.
This isn't a setting in the chat application itself, but in whatever sits in front of it (namely HAProxy and IIS in the old location, nginx in the new location). That's where the discrepancy came from.
We'll also make sure to have these limits configured for other apps as we migrate them, so you don't get the same issue in a couple of months when we migrate the Q&A application.

I tested, I managed to upload 2.5MB image, which wasn't working earlier.
