# Please allow us to disable oneboxing in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, onebox

I'd like to propose a setting for chatrooms that prevents link-only messages from being transformed to oneboxes.

---

Oneboxes have a purpose, and generally speaking they're - sort of - nice to have in chatrooms. Some chatrooms however do not "allow" oneboxes, as they clutter up the transcript. Personally I do not mind oneboxes in "fun" chatrooms (*where having fun is literally all that counts*), but they can be very obnoxious in rooms where discussions take place.

Problems that I see with oneboxes:

- potentially content that I don't want to see, from links I wouldn't open (i.e. images)
- disruptive when it comes to conversations
- oneboxes can be obnoxiously big depending on the source

  ---

**Related:**

- [Overrides/preferences for chat oneboxing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138314/overrides-preferences-for-chat-oneboxing)
- [Can we make oneboxing optional on mobile chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/269871/can-we-make-oneboxing-optional-on-mobile-chat)
- [Make chat oneboxing smaller and less obnoxious - click to enlarge instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158524/make-chat-oneboxing-smaller-and-less-obnoxious-click-to-enlarge-instead)

Comment: Chatrooms that don't allow oneboxing are boring. I fully support this FR.